# Iterate through Razor (SelectList) Parameter in Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor

I have a form with a drop down list that is populated as such:

```
@{
   SelectList categoryList = CSharpHelper<type>(LookupCategory);
}

@Html.DropDownList("TaskCategoryId", categoryList, "Please select a Category")
```

Now this works fine, however I now want to be able to iterate through this **categoryList** parameter within Javascript or JQuery. I would prefer not to iterate through the drop down list itself as I do have a couple of other lists I wish to iterate through as well, but there are no Drop Down Lists for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert any C# property to javascript using `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(object.property))`, eg:

```
<script>
    var categories = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(LookupCategory));
</script>
```

If you have more than one, you could convert your whole Model or create a model javascript object and add to that (to keep better js casing), eg:

```
<script>
     var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
     var model = {};
     model.categories = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Categories));
     model.titles = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Books.Select(x=>x.Title)));
</script>
```